# Cómo acceder a los controles de los labels hijos de paneles generados dinámicamente?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy tratando de acceder a los Labels que son generados dinámicamente dentro de paneles que también son generados de forma dinámica.

De esta forma estoy accediendo a los paneles dinámicos `var reg = pan_principal.Controls.OfType<Panel>();` , y cada iteracion que se da en el `foreach` de la variable reg (es decir, cada item/panel que exista dentro de el panel padre `pan_principal`), me tiene que sacar la información de los Labels hijos que tienen dentro para poder llevarlo a SQL

```
private void btn_Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var reg = pan_principal.Controls.OfType<Panel>();

            foreach (var item in reg)
            {

                var vUnit = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(a => a.Name == "UPriceLbl").FirstOrDefault();
                var refLbl = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(b => b.Name == "refLbl").FirstOrDefault();
                var amountLbl = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(c => c.Name == "amountLbl").FirstOrDefault();
                var total = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(d => d.Name == "totalLbl").FirstOrDefault();


                CONSULTA nuevoRegistro = new CONSULTA();
                nuevoRegistro.HASH = numCompra;
                nuevoRegistro.PRECIO_U = vUnit.ToString();
                nuevoRegistro.REFERENCIA = refLbl.ToString();
                nuevoRegistro.CANTIDAD = amountLbl.ToString();
                nuevoRegistro.SUBTOTAL = total.ToString();

                baseDatos.CONSULTA.Add(nuevoRegistro);
            }

            baseDatos.SaveChanges();
        }
```

He tratado de acceder a ellos de la misma forma en la que estoy accediendo a los paneles, pero no funciona a menos que nombre el panel al que se va a acceder los controles de tipo Label,(no se pueden acceder con el nombre que se le da al panel por que no está en el mismo contexto de ejecución)

¿De qué manera puedo acceder a los valores de los Labels hijos de estos paneles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la forma en que lo estas haciendo no estas accediendo a los labels de ningún panel, sino a los labels que hay en tu formulario, al poner:

```
foreach (var item in reg)
{
   var vUnit = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(a => a.Name =="UPriceLbl").FirstOrDefault();    
}
```

La **palabra clave this** hace referencia al formulario, no al panel, para acceder a  los labels dentro de un panel, te doy estas sugerencias:

```
var paneles = pan_principal.Controls.OfType<Panel>();

foreach (var p in paneles)
{
   var labels = p.Controls.OfType<Label>();   
   var vUnit = labels.Where(a => a.Name == "UPriceLbl").FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Aquí guardamos en la **variable paneles** todos los paneles, y posteriormente mediante un **foreach** recorreríamos todos los paneles guardados en la **variable paneles**, y por cada panel obtendríamos entonces todos sus label almacenándolos en la **variable labels**, y entonces si podemos operar sobre cada label de un panel.

Analiza este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Ur right, gracias!